# The measurement of the interior angles of a triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles, angle

> Given ΔABC, if the exterior angle of A is 68° more than the interior angle of C, the exterior angle of B is 43° more than the interior angle of A, and the exterior angle of C is 25° more than the exterior angle of B. What are the measurements of the interior angles of A, B, and C?

My answer: (Ex means exterior, In means interior)

A = 69 - 111

B = 68 - 112

C = 43 - 137

Ex A - In C = 68

111 - 43 =68

Ex B - In A = 43

112 - 69 =  43

Ex C - Ex B = 25

137 - 112 = 25

I used trial and error but is there a better way to solve this?

Comment: So I would approach this by setting $A,B,C$ to represent the interior angles at $A,B$ and $C$. Then, the statements become
$$
360-A = 68 + C
$$
$$
360 - B = 43 + A
$$
$$
360 - C = 25 + (360-B)
$$
And in addition, we have $A+B+C = 180$. So that's a set of linear equations ...

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the figure:

[image]

The sum of interior angles of triangle is:
$$A+B+C=180^\circ \Rightarrow \\
A+[180^\circ-A-43^\circ]+[180^\circ-A-43^\circ-25^\circ]=180^\circ \Rightarrow\\
A=69^\circ, B=68^\circ,C=43^\circ$$